# How do I replace an XML Node value?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need to replace 2 XML nodes, both postcodes with their correct value. How do I accomplish this in SQL 2005. The XML is in an XML column.

```
<customer><postcode>P22 2XH</postcode></customer>
```

with IP22 2XH

Regards

Rob

Comment: are both nodes in the same record, or one postcode node per record column?

Comment: There are 2 nodes before the postcode node within the customer node. There is 1 postcode node per customer.

Answer (score 1):

Working example to update xml node in a table

```
create table xml (xml xml);
insert xml values('<customer name="John"><postcode>P22 2XH</postcode></customer>');
insert xml values('<customer name="Doe"><postcode>P22 2XH</postcode></customer>');
insert xml values('<customer name="Jane"><postcode>P9 2XH</postcode></customer>');

UPDATE xml
SET xml.modify('
  replace value of (//customer/postcode[text()="P22 2XH"]/text())[1]
  with "IP22 2XH" ');

select * from xml;
```

If you had multiple postcode nodes PER xml-record-column, then you can use the below.  SQL Server only allows one xml node replacement per `modify`, so you need to loop it.

```
create table xml (salesperson varchar(100), portfolios xml);
insert xml values('jim','
    <customer name="John"><postcode>P22 2XH</postcode></customer>
    <customer name="Doe"><postcode>P22 2XH</postcode></customer>
    <customer name="Jane"><postcode>P9 2XH</postcode></customer>');
insert xml values('mary','
    <customer name="Joe"><postcode>Other</postcode></customer>
    <customer name="Public"><postcode>P22 2XH</postcode></customer>');

while exists (
    select * from xml
    cross apply portfolios.nodes('//customer/postcode[text()="P22 2XH"]') n(c))
UPDATE xml
SET portfolios.modify('
  replace value of (//customer/postcode[text()="P22 2XH"]/text())[1]
  with "IP22 2XH" ');
;

select * from xml
```

Comment: That works if you know the position of the problem node, but how do I do this when I don't know it's position? There are thousand of customers. No attributes are available to myself, only node names and values.

Comment: @user - answer updated. //customer searches for customer anywhere in the XML, and then searches for postcode within it